# Extended search option with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling to implement a search function on my website and don’t know how to start with this in javascript.

What I'm trying to do:

When typing in something, e.g. "foo", the script should search in all HTML markup-tags (the tags all have the class "searchopt").

Now the script should change the classes of the mark-up tags that do not contain the searched word (in this case "foo") to class "donotshow".

All mark-tags tags which *do* have the word "foo" inside should not get a new class.

If nothing was found with this word inside, no classes should change, but there should be a text at the top of the body which says that nothing had been found.
Can someone help me get started with this?

Comment: What did you try? Where is your code? Where do you need help? We can help you, but we are not here to do your work!

Comment: Please take this in the spirit in which it is intended - but if your English is poor - you'd be helping yourself to post as much code as you can...

Comment: The problem is I am not very good at javascript and do not even know if it will work. A friend told me here I can get halp with this. i would like it if someone could create a first script (edit) for me. ...I am sorry for the bad english, I am still in school and just am in the second year of learning. I am SO sorry for this!

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how stackoverflow questions are asked

Comment: Ok, it was a bad mistake to go here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: hey hey guys, experts (or hypocrits) stop attacking new users in such way. here can make question only experts and them who know perfectly the rules of the site? no, even begginers, and I am pretty sure that no one has fully read the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask help sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get you started

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Homework</title>

<style>
.searchopt {display:block;}
.donotshow {display:none;}
</style>

</head><body>

Search: <input type="text" onkeyup="
  for( var elms= document.getElementById('content')
                         .getElementsByTagName('p')
       ,      L= elms.length
       ,  found= 0
     ; L--
     ; elms[L].className= ~elms[L].textContent.indexOf(this.value)
                        ? found='searchopt'
                        : 'donotshow'
     );
  this.nextSibling.innerHTML= found ? '' : ' not found' ;
"><span></span><div id="content">
<p class="searchopt">The lazy gray fox crawled under the old tree.</p>
<p class="searchopt">It was a pretty old fox.</p>
<p class="searchopt">This is why he was gray.</p>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Above we used `indexOf` as a way *not* to generate a new regex and use it. `indexOf` will return `-1` (known as a sentinel value) when no result is found. Sentinel values are catched with `~`. The trade-of for this speed optimization is that it's case-sensitive.

**Edit:**

If we want to make this work in a case-insensitive way, we we can no longer dodge using a regex. So we create one and set it to case-insensitive:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Homework</title>

<style>
.searchopt {display:block;}
.donotshow {display:none;}
</style>

</head><body>

Search: <input type="text" onkeyup="
  for( var elms= document.getElementById('content')
                         .getElementsByTagName('p')
       ,      L= elms.length
       ,  found= 0
       ,    rxp= new RegExp(this.value, 'i')
     ; L--
     ; elms[L].className= rxp.test(elms[L].textContent)
                        ? found='searchopt'
                        : 'donotshow'
     );
  this.nextSibling.innerHTML= found ? '' : ' not found' ;
"><span></span><div id="content">
<p class="searchopt">The lazy gray fox crawled under the old tree.</p>
<p class="searchopt">It was a pretty old fox.</p>
<p class="searchopt">This is why he was gray.</p>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: How can I say now that small or big letters are both ok to write into the box?