# Ignore capital and small initial letters

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to set that the use of capital and small initial letters should be ignored in this search script. So if I write "hello" or "HEllo" ... it should bring the same results.

Here is the script:

```
<input type="text" class="boxformal boxformal-cf" placeholder="Diese Seite durchsuchen ..." onkeyup="
for( var elms=document.getElementById('content')
                      .getElementsByTagName('article')
     ,      L=elms.length
   ; L--
   ; elms[L].className= ~elms[L].textContent.indexOf(this.value)
                      ? found='searchopt kurse-standart standart-grau groesse-15'
                      : 'donotshow'
   );
   this.nextSibling.innerHTML= found ? '' : 'Es wurde nichts gefunden!' ;
">
```

Thank you for helping!

P.s.: Some phrases are in German :)

Comment: what a hack is this?

Comment: It is a "search" function, so if you type in a word which you would like to find on my site, all articles which do not have this word inside will be hidden.

Comment: You could probably make use of toLowerCase() to assist in this. Set everything to lowercase then case sensitivity is out of the picture.

Comment: This is why code-readability is an issue. These guys are having trouble seeing that this is a valid for loop because it's very hard to read

Comment: ok, I see now... But ask yourself, if in a few years from now, would you still be able to understand this *for loop*?

Comment: OK, of course you are all right. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about changing the casing of the strings?

```
<input type="text" class="boxformal boxformal-cf" placeholder="Diese Seite durchsuchen ..." onkeyup="
for( var elms=document.getElementById('content')
                      .getElementsByTagName('article')
     ,      L=elms.length
   ; L--
   ; elms[L].className= ~elms[L].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.value.toLowerCase())
                      ? found='searchopt kurse-standart standart-grau groesse-15'
                      : 'donotshow'
   );
   this.nextSibling.innerHTML= found ? '' : 'Es wurde nichts gefunden!' ;
">
```

Comment: Thank you, it works ... I forgot how to set this, but now I know :)

Comment: Warning to future readers: do *not* do this!! The OP didn't tell, but he is using this on numerous amounts of huge texts on one page. The net-result is that pretty much ALL text on the page is copied to a *new* string (in lowercase) on *every* key press (pretty quickly killing the browser due to no more free memory).

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, the follow-up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26894233/588079).

If we want to make this work in a case-insensitive way, we we can no longer dodge using a regex. So we create one and set it to case-insensitive:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Homework</title>

<style>
.searchopt {display:block;}
.donotshow {display:none;}
</style>

</head><body>

Search: <input type="text" onkeyup="
  for( var elms= document.getElementById('content')
                         .getElementsByTagName('p')
       ,      L= elms.length
       ,  found= 0
       ,    rxp= new RegExp(this.value, 'i')
     ; L--
     ; elms[L].className= rxp.test(elms[L].textContent)
                        ? found='searchopt'
                        : 'donotshow'
     );
  this.nextSibling.innerHTML= found ? '' : ' not found' ;
"><span></span><div id="content">
<p class="searchopt">The lazy gray fox crawled under the old tree.</p>
<p class="searchopt">It was a pretty old fox.</p>
<p class="searchopt">This is why he was gray.</p>
</div>

</body></html>
```

This is better then transforming the casing of numerous unknown lengths of strings (the content) *over and over again on each keypress* (something that would pretty much kill the users browser after a few searches because they are *all new* strings)!